# ActionListener works but it never stops checking for user input and does not execute code after

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class Main {
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public boolean isTrue = false;
    public boolean isOn = false; 

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel headerLabel;
    JPanel controlPanel;
    JTextArea textArea;
    JTextField textField;

    public Main (){
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setLayout(null); 

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                System.exit(0);
            }        
        });

        textArea = new JTextArea();

        buttonPanel.add(textArea);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        controlPanel.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

        textField= new JTextField();

        controlPanel.add(textField);

        JButton btn = new JButton("btn");

        buttonPanel.add(btn);

        controlPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);        
        frame.add(controlPanel);
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.add(headerLabel);
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.add(scrollPane);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                btn.setVisible(false);
                textArea.append(newLine+"You pressed the btn");
                isOn=true;    
                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        if(isOn){
                            isOn=false;
                            isTrue=true;
                            String name=textField.getText();
                            textArea.append(newLine+"your chose the name"+name );
                            //... irrelevant code
                            if(isTrue){
                                System.out.println("This is true");
                            }
                        } else{
                            textArea.append(newLine+"Its not time yet.");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        System.out.println(isTrue)
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main(); 
    }
}
```

Once the method reaches actionPerformed it seems to never leave. However whenever there is a new input in textField it prints out the statement in if isTrue but bellow the ActionListener isTrue is false. Some help understand correcting and understanding this would be fantastic.

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, there was a lot of irrelevant code that needed to be edited out and on top of that it did not copy well to the website. I tried to make it as consistent as possible.

Comment: .. layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) `//... irreverent code` ITYM 'irrelevant' there, and it's good you did remove it if so, but can you confirm the code shows the problem without that code?

Comment: *"there was a lot of irrelevant code that needed to be edited out.."* Thanks for doing that. Note that most IDEs have a key combo. that will neatly format code.

Comment: So, ever time `btn` is pressed, you're adding another `ActionListener` to the `textField` - this looks very wrong to me

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I am sure the irrelevant code is irrelevant, all it does is set some variables for calculation in parts of the code that do not interact with the JPanel and prints out a line in the text area.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, The button is set to invisible after the button is pressed, I didn't include that in the code here.

Comment: You're also adding `btn` to more than one container, something that Swing does not allow.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Could you elaborate on this? I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Simply search your code for something.add(btn) -- how many times do you see it? It should only be present *once*. And I strongly second what @MadProgrammer mentioned -- you're re-adding a listener to the JTextField has a very bad code smell to it, and is definitely something that you shouldn't be doing, regardless of whether btn goes invisible or not.

Comment: @Max, `System.getProperty("line.separator");` - don't use that property to add text to the text area. A `Document` in Swing text components will just use `'\n'` for a new line character. When you use the `getText()` method of the text area the `"\n"` will be replaced with the new line string for your OS.